# jquery ajax response, traverse XML to build nested menu tree

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, filter, traversal

I am going nuts trying to figure this out, I am trying to build a simple menu tree with multi levels

```
RootFolder
- First Sub Folder
-- First Sub Sub Folder
--- First Sub Sub Sub Folder
--- First Sub Sub Sub Sub Folder
- Second Sub Folder
- Second Sub Sub Folder
```

My XML is very simple (not the right values)

```
<OrgFolderDetails>
    <FolderName>Main Folder</FolderName>
    <TheChildren>
        <OrgFolderDetails>
            <FolderName>First Sub Folder</FolderName>
            <TheChildren>
                <OrgFolderDetails>
                    <FolderName>First Sub Sub Folder</FolderName>
                    <TheChildren>
                        <OrgFolderDetails>
                            <FolderName>First Sub Siub Sub Folder</FolderName>
                            <TheChildren>
                                <OrgFolderDetails>
                                    <FolderName>First Sub Sub Sub Sub Folder</FolderName>
                                    <TheChildren/>
                                </OrgFolderDetails>
                            </TheChildren>
                        </OrgFolderDetails>
                    </TheChildren>
                </OrgFolderDetails>
            </TheChildren>
        </OrgFolderDetails>
        <OrgFolderDetails>
            <FolderName>Second Sub Folder</FolderName>
            <TheChildren>
                <OrgFolderDetails>
                    <FolderName>Second Sub Sub Folder</FolderName>
                    <TheChildren/>
                </OrgFolderDetails>
            </TheChildren>
        </OrgFolderDetails>
    </TheChildren>
</OrgFolderDetails>
```

I have used jQuery's .filter() and. find() each() without any success, it doesn't give me the nice dashes to indicate which level I am in, it just spits out the folder names.

My code that traverses

```
 $(data).find("FolderName").each(function(){
             var folderName = $(this).text();

            $("#folderLevels").append(folderName+"<br/>");
         });
```

Comment: Can you post your jQuery also, please?

Comment: ahren, thanks, I forgot to add my initial snippet. My concept/approach was trying to locate the position and counting the nested position and adding the # of dashes... No success there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so from what I understand, we need to build a menu, with a certain number of preceding dashes, dependent on the level of the child.
Lucky, jQuery makes this kinda easy.

```
$(data).find("FolderName").each(function(){ 
    var levels = $(this).parents("OrgFolderDetails").size();
    var text = $(this).text();
    var html = "";

    for(var j=0; j < levels; j++){
        html += "-";    
    }
    html += " "+text+"</br>"; //add in that space after the dashes, and the <br>

    $("#folderLevels").append(html);
});
```

Hope that helps. The main helper in this is the `parents()` method.
http://api.jquery.com/parents

Comment: OMG, are you serious... I see your approach, that works well, thank you very much... your code teaches me a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to use a recursive function for this.

```
var s = getNestedString($(data), 0);

function getNestedString(d, level) {
    // get the name of current node
    var s = d.children("FolderName").text() + "<br/>";

    // prepend with dashes for inner levels
    for (var i=0 ; i<level ; i++) {
        s = "-" + s;
    }

    // get children and call this function recursively (incrementing level)
    var ch = d.children("TheChildren").children("OrgFolderDetails");
    for (var i=0 ; i < ch.length ; i++) {
        s = s + getNestedString(ch[i], level+1);
    }

    // return string for current and nested nodes
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I will check this out too, thanks for the quick response, I was ripping my hair out!

Comment: @GuMingPeng I don't think mine works actually, plus ahren's answer is better (simpler).  I thought you could use *children* since it exists in JQuery, but apparently not.